# NSWorkspace SetIcon not updating application icon on El Capitan

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

I am using NSWorkSpace `SetIcon:forFile:options:` for changing application icon. On Yosemite it is working fine. However on El Capitan application icon is not updating.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone.
Try to set nil icon first and then your icon:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:nil forFile:path options:0]
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:image forFile:path options:0];
```

Comment: Hello @EdiZ. The above solution is not working. is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem on OSx 10.14.6. I use the workaround where we set the icon after a delay after creating the file. Immediately setting the icon was working sometimes and not refreshing sometimes despite returning success.

```
    auto nspath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:path.c_str()];
    auto nsdata = [contents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:nspath error:nil];
    auto ret = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:nspath contents:nsdata attributes:nil];
    // hide the extension of the file after creation.
    if (ret) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{NSFileExtensionHidden: @true} ofItemAtPath:nspath error:nil];
        // set the icon, after a delay. Bug in OSx, the icon is not reflected sometimes despite YES return
        // if it is set immediately after creating the file.
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            auto img = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Icon"];
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:img forFile:nspath options:0];
        });
    }
```