# Delay in customizing icons with local files for mac app (Use setIcon)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, customization

1. Do not set **"CFBundleIconFile"**.
2. Determine if the icon file exists. Change the icon if it exists.

Use setIcon in mac app.

```
NSImage * iconImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:iconPath];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
setIcon: iconImage
forFile: thisAppPath
options: 0];
```

Question:

1. I recompile the application and start it **at least three times before** the icon changes.
2. Even stranger, after launching the app more times, it **changes back** to the default blank icon.
3. I packaged the app with the changed icons and downloaded it on another machine, but the icons are still blank.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSWorkspace SetIcon not updating application icon on El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608339/nsworkspace-seticon-not-updating-application-icon-on-el-capitan)

Comment: thx. It did not work.